# PyCharm и подсветка ошибок

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, ide

Код подсвечивается как ошибочный, но PC думает, что тут написано "loerwer" (было написано до изменения. Пробовал перезапускать, сбрасывать настройки, но не помогает. Как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Версия PyCharm свежая?

Comment: @gil9red уже решил проблему установкой самое свежей версии. Интересно то, что версия была почти самая новая

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обновление версии `PyCharm` решило проблему.